# How can I remove all potentially cached tokens or session IDs on Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-oauth

An odd question, but hopefully someone has an answer.

I am developing a mobile app that will connect with Facebook.  Everything was working fine and had been for about a week.  I could authorize and remove authorization and post to a user's feed.

On Saturday or Sunday I modified my request to add offline_access.  Around that time (unfortunately I cannot be sure exactly when) I started receiving failures coming back saying the access token was invalid ("Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password.").

I know this to be false because I haven't changed my password and I just received the access token and the responses were all fine.  In fact, I post to the feed immediately after getting authorized ("Hey, I'm using TheApp") and that post fails with the above error.

Here's where it escalates: I went to the mobile Facebook app to verify access and connectivity.  Suddenly the official FB app starts giving me the same problems.  It starts popping up login dialogs.  I enter my password, it shows a toast saying login succeeded and then asks for the login again a few seconds later.  After a try or two of this it ends up displaying another toast with the invalid token message from above.

I clear my app, uninstall it, logout and clear all FB data (using Manage Apps in the device settings), and force stop the app.  I can't uninstall FB so that's the most I can do.  I also go to the FB site and change my FB password.  I go back to the FB app, login again, and before the feed activity even finishes loading it's prompting me for my password again and we're back into that old cycle.  I try my app and it's in the same bucket (no surprise there).

Two more data points:

- I can sometimes get this same behaviour to occur using the Graph API Exlorer web app.  I can do it consistently with a token for the Graph API Explorer itself and I can get it inconsistently with an access token from my app.
- I fired up an emulator (one without the FB app) and ran my app there.  Logging in as me I can get an access token and everything works.  My app posts to my feed with no complaints.

At this point, FB (and apparently any FB-connecting app) is hosed on my real device.  It is either just the device or a combination of the device plus my account (I haven't any other FB account to try).

Can anyone shed some light on what I need to do to either debug this further or clear it up?

Comment: I don't see a programming question. This belongs on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: This is directly arising because of my use of the Facebook API in an Android app under development.  Is that not relevant?   I'll check superuser.com (never knew of it before) but I'm willing to bet someone will say it's a developer issue and point me back here.  Edit: Yeah, I don't see how this could fit on superuser.com.  This is an OAuth token/session cache issue either on the device or on the server.  If I need to post code (which isn't really relevant) I can do that but it won't clear anything up.

Comment: I seem to have run in to the same problem, see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494049/the-session-has-been-invalidated-because-the-user-has-changed-the-password  And there is another related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517968/access-token-immediately-invalidated/8533747#8533747