# The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova

Implementing a PhoneGap app for Android and iOS, the app is using Facebook Connect and the PhoneGap Facebook Connect Plugin (https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect). A few days ago I started having problem with the access_token, but only on Android, the same scenario works on iOS without problems. The step by step is:

1. Init facebook. (using plugin function)
2. Login to facebook.  (using plugin function) (asking the permissions: 'email user_birthday publish_stream offline_access')
3. Do graph api call /me using the token returned to me.

Step 3 returns error, and when I take the url called and put in a desktop browser, it gives me the error "The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password".

Sandbox app/ non-sandbox app does not make any difference.

The exact same steps in iOS works fine.

I saw a lot of questions on SOF and facebook about it, but all of them are referring to letting the user do the auth flow again, or that the problem solved itself after a few days.... Is there someone that can confirm that this is really a facebook bug? Or have a solution? Or can explain why it works on Android and not iOS? Maybe it could have to do with me in iOS not using the facebook app, but choosing to always go via the OAuth in browser?

Thanks for any clues!

EDIT:

Found to other related questions, that seems to have the same root cause as mine.

[How can I remove all potentially cached tokens or session IDs on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883524/how-can-i-remove-all-potentially-cached-tokens-or-session-ids-on-android)

[Access token immediately invalidated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517968/access-token-immediately-invalidated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in the end I found out that the root cause of my problem was that Android and iOS facebook SDK's are handling the offline_access differently, in the value that they set in the 'expires' parameter in the session object.

In iOS, 'expires' will be set to a date far far in the future (4001-01-01), while in Android 'expires' will be set to 0. This made my comparison (expired < today) fail (I was doing a date parse to milliseconds), and the session was always 'invalid'.

(then in my case i was always doing a logout if the session was invalid, which made my token be invalid for real when trying it in the browser afterwards.. doh..)