# How to make longer facebook Graph API session for android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I saw this question: [The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494049/the-session-has-been-invalidated-because-the-user-has-changed-the-password/11449321#11449321) while I was searching for an answer for the very same question, but I don't know how to make the session longer for android so could someone tell me how. I think that just those two lines must be changed :

```
String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
```

But I don't have any idea how must they be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's mentioned in a [reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#extend_token):

> Step 8: Extending the access token
>
> With the deprecation of offline_access, you need to extend your
>   access_token every time a user opens your app. To do this, call
>   facebook method extendAccessTokenIfNeeded in your application's
>   onResume() function:
>
> public void onResume() {
>       super.onResume();
>       facebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null); 
>   }
>
> Note: Make sure you have the latest android SDK available at
>   https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/