# Access token immediately invalidated

Tags: authorization, access-token, facebook-oauth

for a few users (maybe not that few, considering the number of related mails I'm receiving) the access token associated with an OAUTH authorization seems to be immediately invalidated. The user is guided through the usual authorization process, he accepts the permissions, he is redirected to the right page which includes the access token, but as soon as my application tries to use the access token to get the user ID, an error is received instead:

```
{"error":{"message":"Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 0. The current unix time is 1323939801.","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

The offline_access is part of the permissions. Besides, there's no way the cause is the user removing the authorization or changing password since this happens right after having accepted the authorization. In my app flow I already attempt a retry a few times and from the logs I receive I can see the error is always the same: guiding the user through the authorization process again has no use, since the user is redirected again to the page with the access_token in the fragment. Apparently the only way for a user to solve this is to remove the application from the list of authorized applications and do the same thing all over again (unless at the n-th retry it starts working, not all users write back when things start working).

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Experiencing the same problem with Facebook iOS SDK. Getting errors for the tokens with offline_access right after authorizing. Some of the tokens are working fine in minute later.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have run into the same problem, see my question here: [The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494049/the-session-has-been-invalidated-because-the-user-has-changed-the-password) -> EDIT: i dont think this is the same thing any more, i found the rootcause for this, see answer for that question.

And another related question here: [How can I remove all potentially cached tokens or session IDs on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883524/how-can-i-remove-all-potentially-cached-tokens-or-session-ids-on-android#autocomment10569410)

Any clues yet..?

Comment: No clue unfortunately, and it keeps on happening: very frustrating.

Comment: I don't know your code, and where you get this error message. But just to share my experience: When asking for offline_access, it seems that different facebook SDKs sets the 'expires' parameter in the session to different things. I am using the Android and the iOS SDK, and for iOS 'expires' gets a date 4001-01-01, while in Android 'expires' will be set to 0. This fooled me at least and made me have to correct the logic to not make my app think that the session was expired. Maybe it could help someone.. :)

Comment: I don't use any Facebook SDK: I issue direct Graph requests using the HttpClient classes in Android, meaning I send simple GET requests and parse the responses myself. For authorizing I simply redirect users to the WAP version of the OAUTH dialog in a WebView: I don't know if that's what's setting the expires value to 0 as you said.

Comment: Actually, I believe that 'expires' params does not involved anyhow when asking for 'offline_access' because the token never expires in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Offline access is getting deprecated, I wouldn't ask for it anymore. Instead, in iOS SDK, at least, there's a renewal method.

Comment: My question dates back to 6 months ago, it's not like I'm still asking... ;)

Comment: I know of the renewal method, but it doesn't work as expected in my case (tokens' lifetime not being extended), and it looks like it's the same for many other people too. I opened another item on StackOverflow, and I'm following all the related bugs other developers posted on Facebook itself.

Comment: Yeah just saying- I just implemented both iOS and Android, and haven't run into expiration issues. But also, not asking for offline_access.